# How can I save menu state with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, save, state

I am trying to save the state of a menu as a link is clicked from a menu and loads a new page.
This is a multi-level push menu which has categories and then sub category links under each category.

Main menu kicks out after clicked

Main menu has category links
click on category link and menu pushes out a submenu - new category menu
select a submenu link from the submenu category 
Once submenu link is clicked and loads to the link which was clicked
The menu should save the state of where it is in the levels as per clicks.

The title of a category should still be present if a link under a category is clicked. At the moment what is happening now is that when I click on a link under a category it loads the page of the clicked link but the menu resets and goes back to the top level.

A link to the sample of what I am talking about is [this](http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/).

I am not sure how to do this as I have not implemented any decent solution of how I would like to do this.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: use the location.hash parameter. more code is needed to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several ways that this could be accomplished depending on what your overall goal is.

First - you could use a cookie to save the state between pages.  This is fairly easy to implement and doesn't require any server-side code.

Second - you could even use a database but that's a little overkill unless you're already working with a database.

Third - use Javascript to determine where the menu should be based on the current page location.  This is my recommendation - it's very quick/easy/lightweight.  Theoretically, if a user navigated to a page, then they would have gotten there through the menu and would be at the exact spot in the menu every time.

Here's a quick example using straight Javascript.  This code is a dynamically generating a basic menu that sets the class of the active menu item based on the current URL.  You could easily accomplish something similar with nested menus.  Take a look and let me know if you have any questions:

```
(function () {
    var html = "<div class=\"menu\">" +
                      "<div id=\"Page1MenuItem\"><a href=\"page1.html\">Page1</a></div>" +
                      "<div id=\"Page2MenuItem\"><a href=\"page2.html\">Page2</a></div>" +
                      "<div id=\"Page3MenuItem\"><a href=\"page3.html\">Page3</a></div>" +
                      "<div id=\"Page4MenuItem\"><a href=\"page4.html\">Page4</a></div>" +
                      "<div id=\"Page5MenuItem\"><a href=\"page5.html\">Page5</a></div>" +
                "</div>";
    document.getElementById("MenuContainer").innerHTML = html;
    var currentUrl = window.location.pathname.toLowerCase();
    switch (currentUrl) {
        case "/page1.html":
            document.getElementById("Page1MenuItem").setAttribute("class", "current");
            break;
        case "/page2.html":
            document.getElementById("Page2MenuItem").setAttribute("class", "current");
            break;
        case "/page3.html":
            document.getElementById("Page3MenuItem").setAttribute("class", "current");
            break;
        case "/page4.html":
            document.getElementById("Page4MenuItem").setAttribute("class", "current");
            break;
        case "/page5.html":
            document.getElementById("Page5MenuItem").setAttribute("class", "current");
            break;
    }
})();
```